# Firebase screen class not set

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am facing trouble getting the right data from Firebase automatic screen reporting Analytics. I have tried everything, from checking the name and class of all my ViewControllers to manually set the name and class using `Analytics.setScreenName("Screen1", screenClass: "Screen1")`. But I keep getting **(not set)** for the most used screen? Does anybody knows what could be causing this?

I have this on my Firebase console:
[image: Incorrect screen class]
[image: Incorrect screen name]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this for the iOS Unity app using Firebase Unity SDK? If not, can you share the code. Make sure that the screens are not using controllers.

Comment: No, this is for an iOS app using Firebase Pod. I can't share the code, there are too many controllers and it is a private project. You mean having a reference to a View Controller from a custom view?

Comment: What is the Firebase Analytics SDK version? (You can see on the log). Also, can you please share the Pod file or Podfile.lock content? Thanks

Comment: @omaestra did you solve this problem ? Can you tell me how?

Comment: Hi @slytrkmn, sorry for my late response. I have solved this going through all my ViewControllers and implementing the super.viewDidLoad() call in all the viewDidLoad method.

From Firebase Support Team: "If you implement viewDidAppear in your UIViewController but do not call [super viewDidAppear:], that screen class will not be automatically tracked."

Comment: they mention viewDidAppear() in them internal SKD document

 setScreenName:screenClass: must be called after
/// [super viewDidAppear:].

Comment: @AmrAngry can you link to this reference that it must be called after?

Comment: Hi @Peter Lapisu
It's been a while since I replied to this post, and things might have changed since then. I recommend checking out the Firebase example in the SDK for the latest information. 